Markov chain on the real line: Numerical methods for evaluating the stationary distribution
Consider a Markov chain on the real line with transition probabilities
$$
p(x_0,x)=\mathbf 1_{\{x\geq x_0+\alpha\,\cup\,x\leq x_0-\beta\}}\phi(x)+\delta(x-x_0)\left(\Phi(x_0+\alpha)-\Phi(x_0-\beta)\right),
$$
where $\alpha,\beta\geq 0$, and $\phi(\cdot)$ and $\Phi(\cdot)$ are the standard normal density and distribution, respectively.
I am interested in numerically evaluating the stationary density $\pi(x|\alpha,\beta)$ satisfying
$$
\pi(x)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \pi(x_0)p(x_0,x)\,\mathrm dx_0.
$$
Evaluating the r.h.s. and simplifying gives the equality
$$
\tag{1}
\frac{\pi(x)}{1-\int_{x-\alpha}^{x+\beta}\pi(t)\,\mathrm dt}=\frac{\phi(x)}{1-\int_{x-\beta}^{x+\alpha}\phi(t)\,\mathrm dt}.
$$
For the special case $\alpha=\beta$ we have the solution $\pi(x)=\phi(x)$.
Are there any numerical methods that can leverage $(1)$ and the special case for $\alpha=\beta$ to evaluate $\pi$ for $\alpha\neq\beta$? As pointed out by @RW, the existence of $\pi$ for $\alpha\neq\beta$ is still unresolved.

How do you know that a stationary distribution exists?

@RW I'm not sure for $\alpha\neq\beta$ but for the special case $\alpha=\beta$ you showed me it does exist.

Yes - I remember, but that argument doesn't work in the asymmetric case, and the normal distribution itself is no longer stationary.
